# How to pass enum to values to a dropdown in template [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I've recently started with typescript. I've created a dropdown using `select` and `option` tags in the template.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="primaryMode" (ngModelChange)="primaryModeChangeHandler($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let mode of modes" [value]="mode">{{mode}}</option>
</select>
```

and in typescript I was having an array:

```
modes= ['Calendar Year', 'Year-to-date', 'Rolling Year', 'Custom'];
```

But my tech lead said that I've to use `enum` instead of array. Here's my code now:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ... } from '@angular/core';

export enum presetRange {
    CalendarYear,
    YearToDate,
    RollingYear,
    CustomRange
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timeselector',
  templateUrl: './timeselector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timeselector.component.css']
})
export class TimeselectorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  primaryMode;

  primaryModeChangeHandler(event) {
    console.log(this.primaryMode);    
  }
}
```

But the problem is that I don't know how to bind dropdown to an enum. I tried few things but I failed. Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r8bcby). Please correct me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String enums require a key and a value. And enums are used to create named constants, they don't produce a list. So you still need an array, but created from the values of the enum.

Controller

```js
enum PresetRange {
  CalendarYear = 'Calendar Year',
  YearToDate = 'Year-to-date',
  RollingYear = 'Rolling Year',
  CustomRange = 'Custom'
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timeselector',
  templateUrl: './timeselector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timeselector.component.css']
})
export class TimeselectorComponent implements OnInit {
  primaryMode: any;
  modesLabels = [                        // <-- you still need the array
    PresetRange.CalendarYear, 
    PresetRange.YearToDate, 
    PresetRange.RollingYear,
    PresetRange.CustomRange 
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  primaryModeChangeHandler(event) {
    console.log(this.primaryMode);    
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="primaryMode" (ngModelChange)="primaryModeChangeHandler($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let label of modesLabels" [value]="label">{{label}}</option>
</select>
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uexcpq)

Comment: Actually this is what my tech lead said: "Pass enums as value and modesLabels(say) as display strings to option in your dropdown".

Comment: He/she meant you to rename `modes` variable as `modesLabels`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Well, my tech lead is a lady. She told me to make those changes. But anyway, this solution is correct. Let me show this to her. :-)

Comment: I wonder if there is 100 enum types , will you write 100 times there ?

Comment: This is an enum for a drop down list. If the list is going to contain 100 options, then they might be initialized differently. But at the moment, writing clear code is better than writing for the future (that might never occur).

Comment: Developer always takes care of worst scenarios. In the future enums will maybe come from backend and customer wants more then for this you need to create new publish for just one more row. In my opinion, not good approach

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7fjpcx) You can use `Object.keys` for this or you can write custom pipeline for this.

In component

```
  modes =[];
  enums = presetRange 

  constructor() {this.modes= Object.keys(this.enums).filter(Number) }
```

in html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="primaryMode" (ngModelChange)="primaryModeChangeHandler($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let key of modes" [value]="key" >{{enums[key]}}</option>
</select>
```